# Pattern matching an int against a set of sets of ints

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Example:

you have two lists ("categories"):

```
catLow  = [1,2,3,4,5]
catHigh = [6,7,8,9,10]
```

Using pattern matching, how do you decide whether

```
val x = 7
```

Is within the first list (category) or the second one?

That's the general problem. My specific problem is doing that but in my case X is within a list as in:

```
val l = [1,7,2,4]
```

and I want to match it against something like:

```
case catHigh :: tail // i.e. starts with a "high" number
case _ :: catLow :: tail // i.e. second element is a "low" number
// where "high" and "low" are example category names implemented as lists
```

Comment: This isn't really suited to pattern matching, as you not interested in the value of `x`, but rather checking to see if `x` is in two different collections. Have you looked into how [extraction](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/112) is performed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
scala> class Cat( xs:Set[Int] ) {
  def unapply( x:Int ) = if ( xs contains x ) Some(x) else None
}
defined class Cat

scala> object CatLow extends Cat( Set(1,2,3,4,5) )
defined object CatLow

scala> object CatHigh extends Cat( Set(6,7,8,9,10) )
defined object CatHigh

scala> def decode( zs:List[Int] ):Unit = zs match {
  case Nil =>
  case CatLow(z)::tail =>
    println("Low  "+z)
    decode(tail)
  case CatHigh(z)::tail =>
    println("High "+z)
    decode(tail)
  case z::tail =>
    println("???? "+z)
    decode(tail) 
}
decode: (zs: List[Int])Unit

scala> decode( List(1,7,2,0,4) )
Low  1
High 7
Low  2
???? 0
Low  4
```

Comment: thanks, but what advantage do you get compared to just using Sets like how wingedsubmariner suggested?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with wingedsubmariner's answer; we were working concurrently.  I wrote it this way because I thought you were looking for a pattern that completely encapsulates the test.  If you are OK with putting the test in a guard after the pattern, then the other answer is fine, but it sounded like you were asking for this.

Comment: yeah, I was just about to say that I have just noticed that. This approach allows me to write the whole thing in the "case" itself without using "if" etc. Thanks, I was actually just about to do it this way instead. I will make a performance comparison, though. I will use guards instead if it happens to be significantly faster

Comment: Yes, if this is performance-critical code, then it is certainly worth checking what the JVM's optimizer can do with this.

Comment: well, it is around 25% slower than using guards. I ran a microbenchmark on a list of 2 elements.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51920/discussion-between-amigonico-and-space-monkey)

Answer (score 4):

```
val lowSet = Set(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val highSet = Set(6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

someList match {
  case catHigh :: tail if highSet(catHigh) => ...
  case _ :: catLow :: tail if lowSet(catLow) => ...
}
```

A `Set` can be used as a function that returns whether the passed element is in the `Set`. Then, in the match statement, you can use pattern guards (introduced with `if`) to check whether matched values are in the set.

Comment: great, thank you! I will wonder what the performance will be like. I will check it.

Comment: I think sometimes a custom extractor obscures the logic. This seems clear to me.

Comment: Btw, sorry for unmarking your answer is the solution. The other answer seems more like the "natural" one even though yours is better for performance and probably what I will go for given my particular project where I would need to do this matching bit billions of times.

Comment: @Spacemonkey Don't worry about it :) AmigoNico's answer is closer to what your question was asking for.